# Parsing a text file with tweets to csv with '|' delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing, text

I have a .txt file containing geotagged tweets. The information is delimited by '|' character. The information (which can be perceived as columns) are datetime, latitude, longitude and tweet_text.

```
Date_time|latitude|longitude|tweet_text
Mon Jan 01 09:09:57 +0000 2018|-37.8140362|144.9644232|terima kasih 2017 yang ohsem. semoga 2018 akan lebih baik lagi.-selamat tahun baru rakan-rakanâ€¦ 
Mon Jan 01 09:15:54 +0000 2018|-37.81639|144.9655|we love christmas and new year proposals! happy new year to everyone celebrating love this yearâ€¦ 
Mon Jan 01 09:42:08 +0000 2018|-37.818|144.985|@michaelpaynter entertaining everyone at yarra park nye event #melbourne| #nye #musicâ€¦ 
Mon Jan 01 09:45:16 +0000 2018|-37.818|144.985|@emilyurbandiva and brother @jwilliamsimusik entertaining everyone at yarra park nye eventâ€|¦
```

Initially, I used

```
data = pd.read_csv('MelbCBD_scs2018_new.txt',sep="|", header=None)
```

, but it threw parsing error whenever the tweet_text had '|'.

I tried manually cleaning tweet_text but it is too much work for large files. Hence I changed the argument parameter of read_csv.

```
data = pd.read_csv('MelbCBD_scs2018_new.txt',sep="|", header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,error_bad_lines=False)
```

But it displays the following warning and skips those lines (essentially the tweets) which I do not want.

```
b'Skipping line 340: expected 4 fields, saw 5
```

I would ideally like a code that removes any special character after encountering 3 '|' characters in each line of the .txt file i.e. the tweet_text column and parses it into the .csv file, without skipping any line.

Comment: I would (personally) separate this into two pieces, the first of which is your actual problem, and simply re-write the data into a new file. Then you can just read as normal. The | being inside tweets means that it's not exactly a | delimited file---I know this isn't news to you, but I think your question should moreso be how to correct your delimited file. In which case, why not just write a script that replaces the delimiters?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can you suggest a delimeter that for sure will not be present in the tweet_text?

Comment: Actually the best idea is just to introduce quotes around the text; the pipes inside of a quoted string won't be assumed to be a delimiter. For e.g. a CSV line that was like `1.0,1.1,"hello, wold","etc"` would parse into four columns, not 5. Alternatively, you can replace the delimiters with ASCII delimiters---these are non-printable characters that aren't on keyboards, so are unlikely to be in a tweet. The ascii characters 28-31 are reserved for different delimits.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I will try that out. But is there a solution where somehow I could specify the number of columns in the beginning so that the code does not consider any '|' after the third one as a delimeter.

Comment: Aside: The `|` character is known as a "pipe". Your data file would be called a "pipe delimited file".

Comment: @alkasm's suggestion about quoting your data is the best long term solution. In a delimited file fields with embedded delimiters should be quoted. That's a very standard rule across all delimited file parsers. Ensuring your data file is a correctly quoted delimited file will go the furthest towards ensuring that it will be handled correctly, even when the program handling it needs to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was just a matter of specifying the number of columns by specifying the column names.

```
data = pd.read_csv('MelbCBD_scs2018_new.txt', sep="|", names = ["Date_time", "latitude", "longitude","tweet_text"], header=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,error_bad_lines=False)
```

Now, this returns every single line without skipping and stores it in the dataframe named 'data'.

Comment: Cool! I thought about this solution, but wasn't sure if it would work.